# how to import database created in microsoft sql server 2005 to MySql server 5.0

Tags: mysql, sql-server-2005

I have created database in microsoft sql server 2005 can i use that particular database in mysql server 5.0 .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no common way to perform such kind of migration because of much of differences between these two RDBMS.
The quick suggestion can be: export you MSSQL database into SQL file, open it via favorite text editor, remove MSSQL specific instructions, and load into MySQL using mysql console tool.

This way should be OK for non-complex databases without complex constraints, foreign keys and stored procedures.
Otherwise, you'll need to rewrite these type of database artifacts using MySQL dialect.

Comment: Thanks for the reply ,its better to rewrite in mysql

Comment: Yeah, i don't think it'll be difficult. Otherwise StackOverflow will help you :)